# Can I use the phrase "some of mine" this way?

Tags: meaning-in-context, possessive-pronouns

> and when I needed some of mine, by chance everyone turned out to be busy.

I mean to say I helped my acquaintances before and when I needed some of them, they pretended to be busy in my bad situation. No one was helpful.

Is it fine to use “some of mine” in that context?

Comment: The half sentence you have written isn't really enough context to work out what "mine" could be referring to.

Comment: James K, please note that I used ‘everyone’ in the second sentence!

Comment: Second sentence?  There isn't even one sentence here!

Comment: James K, I ain’t a grammarian or native speaker. I’m here just to learn English. Please let me know the mistakes of the sentence so that I can improve my English.

Comment: James K, to my knowledge, the first one is a dependent clause, and the second is an independent. But if there are any mistakes, they are not sentences at all.

Comment: The first one is an incomplete sentence: 
“and when I needed some of mine,”

A sentence that contains a subject and verb but does not express a complete thought is also known as a dependent clause fragment:

Incorrect: if she feels like going

Although there is a subject (she) and verb feels in this clause, it does not express a complete thought is considered a fragment. 

Correct: if she feels like going, she will arrive later.

(written by Monmouth University)

Comment: The quote starts with "and", which is a conjunction. So this seems to be the second half of a sentence made of two coordinated parts.  This part seems to have a dependent clause  "when...mine" and an independent clause "by chance everyone...busy".  That independent clause *could* be a complete sentence. However it is not a complete sentence.  "clause != sentence"  and "Independent clause != sentence".

Comment: OP, the best advice I can give you is to really learn what a sentence is. It will make talking about them easier.

Comment: Let me help you here, Jay. You needed to make up some context, as I have done in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

No.  *Some of mine* means *some of the things (previously mentioned) that belong to me*.

> You are wet through. While your clothes are drying, you can borrow some of mine.

To express the meaning you want, you could say "When I needed *their* help" or "When I needed some of them to help me".

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/mine


something or someone belonging to or associated with me.
e.g.
mine is best.

Is it not to refer to the person who is connected with me, i.e., my husband, my children, my blood ties, my friends?

Comment: _Me and mine_ is a rather old-fashioned expression for _me and my family/loved ones_, but you can't use _mine_ on its own to mean _my friends._ It would only mean _my husband_ if you had just mentioned husbands.

Comment: Thank you. Is this fine?: We hate our blood ties, after all ‘ours are ours’. We can’t betray them. 

Does “ours” mean blood ties?

Comment: _Me and mine_ and _you and yours_ are established expressions, but _we and ours_ is not. Using _ours_ to mean relatives following a reference to 'blood ties' would probably be understood, but is not very idiomatic.

Comment: I have loads of friends. You have few friends. [Sorry, Kate. :)] Some of mine are very rich.

Comment: @Lambie - You seem to be agreeing with me. As I said in my earlier comment, _mine_ only means _my husband_ if you have just mentioned husbands, _my friends_ if you have just mentioned friends.

Comment: I guess I read your first sentence and thought that "my friends" are not something that *belong* to one, but could still be called nevertheless *mine*.

Answer (score 0):

"and when I needed some of mine, by chance everyone turned out to be busy".

Situation: I have loads of friends, some are very nice, others aren't. They ask me to help them all the time. I always do.

But when I needed some of mine [some of my friends] to help me, they turned me down.

So yes, some of mine is fine.